# the event which is called on read request from bluetoothle in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to read the value which comes from bluetooth le device. the problem is that I don't know is any event calling on read request from device in ionic app?
I'm using bluetoothle plugin!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an event when the value changes you can use `startNotification`: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#startnotification

It takes a callback function as argument that gets called when data has been successfully received.